# Why does my dynamically created user control doesn't fire button click event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

i have a problem with user control.
i create it dynamically on my aspx page after clicking on a button:

```
protected void btnAddRules_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        RuleProperty Control = (RuleProperty)LoadControl("RuleProperty.ascx");         
        MyPanel.Controls.Add(Control);
    }
```

when i click on a button of my user control, the button event wont fire and the user control will disappear. here is the button event:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WowzaRule rule = GetRuleFromGUI();
        RuleList.Add(rule);
        //Session["RuleList"] = RuleList;
        //List<WowzaRule> test = new List<WowzaRule>();
        SaveToXMLFiles(txtdbnum.Text, RuleList);
    }
```

i understand that after pressing the button on mypage the usercontrol is released and if its not created on pag_init or page Load it wont stay, but i need to create it on my button click event and find a way for it not to disapper.

thanks in advance, Daniel

Comment: You have marked question with `winforms` tag, but it looks like you have asp.net application with web forms

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add an event handler that it can fire the click event and call your delegate

```
Control.Click += btnAdd_Click1;
```

Comment: Where Should i add it ?

Comment: My User Control is not a button. Icant write Control.Click i dont have this option...

Comment: ... you have to expose that Click event by your user control and redirect it to the event of the button within your user control

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically created controls, once added, have to be on a page on *every* page load in order to work correctly. What happens in your case:

1. `RuleProperty` is added after the button click
2. Page loads with this control
3. User clicks on the button within `RuleProperty`
4. Control is not added to the control tree during the page load (corresponding code is only in the button click handler, and that button was not clicked)
5. ASP.NET does not know which control triggered the event, so the event is not processed

To go around this issue you need to add you control on every page loading, for example using some flag stored in `ViewState`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ViewState["AddRuleProperty"] != null && (bool)ViewState["AddRuleProperty"])
    {
        AddRulePropertyControl();
    }
}

protected void btnAddRules_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddRulePropertyControl();          
    ViewState["AddRuleProperty"] = true;
}

private void AddRulePropertyControl()
{
    RuleProperty Control = (RuleProperty)LoadControl("RuleProperty.ascx");         
    MyPanel.Controls.Add(Control);
}
```

**Update.**

If you want to remove the control from the page later on in the control's click handler, you need to remove corresponding ViewState key. This is not possible from the control directly, since property `Page.ViewState` is protected, and also this would have created an unwanted dependency.

What seems as the right way to do this is to subscribe to the very same event from the Page (you might need to make this event visible from the controller) and reset the key in there. Like this:

```
private void AddRulePropertyControl()
{
    RuleProperty Control = (RuleProperty)LoadControl("RuleProperty.ascx");         
    Control.ButtonClick += RuleProperty_ButtonClick;
    MyPanel.Controls.Add(Control);
}

private void RuleProperty_ButtonClick()
{
    ViewState["AddRuleProperty"] = false;
}
```

Please note that event name here is not real, this is just a sketch of what can be done.

Comment: One More Thing, How can i go back to my page after the button event of the user control is done ?

Comment: Do you mean "how do I remove the control"? If yes, then just reset to false the ViewState flag in the `btnAdd_Click1`.

Comment: That should have worked. Could you post the code you have tried?

Comment: protected void btnAdd_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WowzaRule rule = GetRuleFromGUI();
            RuleList.Add(rule);        
            SaveToXMLFiles(txtdbnum.Text, RuleList);
            ViewState["AddRuleProperty"] = false;
        }

Comment: does the ViewState works like session or is it attached to every page diffrently? maybe thats the reason it dosent work ?

Comment: No, ViewState is page-specific. However this is not an issue here - you are adding control to the same page. But the problem here (sorry, I should have thought of it myself) is that `Control.ViewState` is not the parent page's ViewState, so you are effectively working with two keys here. However I think I came up with a solution. Will update the post shortly.